# MiniShift error virNetSocketReadWire:1806

Tags: minishift

How do I deal with this error? I'm getting it after I ran `minishift start` in a VM without nested virtualization turned on? I've now turned it on, but keep seeing errors that look like file corruption.

```
error : virNetSocketReadWire:1806 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error
```

I'm seeing it in /var/log/messages, sytemctl's output from libvirtd status and when I run minishift start.

Answer (score 0):

Run `minishift delete` to clean up the environment as it is only partially setup and the run `minishift start` to get going again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing qemu driver.

```
yum -y install libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu && systemctl restart libvirtd
```